# Apache Iginte BinaryObject SqlFieldsQuery

Tags: java, ignite

Is there any way to run sql fields query on apache ignite for binary object (without defining java class)?

I want to execute something like this:

```
    CacheConfiguration<Integer, Object> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();
    cfg.setName("test_bo");
    cfg.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, BinaryObject.class);

    IgniteCache<Integer, Object> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);
    BinaryObjectBuilder builder = ignite.binary().builder(BinaryObject.class.getName());
    BinaryObject object = builder.setField("xxx", "yyy").build();
    cache.put(1, object);
    List<Object[]> collect = cache.withKeepBinary().query(
        new SqlFieldsQuery("select xxx from BinaryObject")).getAll().stream()
            .map(list -> list.toArray(new Object[list.size()]))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    assertThat(collect).containsExactly(new Object[]{"yyy"});
```

But I've got an exception that field is not defined:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "XXX" not found; SQL statement: select xxx from BinaryObject [42122-175]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BinaryObject is an interface that doesn't have any indexes definitions. You need to pass an exact class definition of your domain class to `CacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(...)` on the client side, that should have class definitions, and Ignite will gather information on indexes that are set up.

If you don't have classes at all (even on the client side) then you can define indexes using QueryEntity directly as described [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-queries#configuring-sql-indexes-using-queryentity).

Also there is no need to make an object to be a type of `BinaryObject`. Your objects will be stored in this format on the server side automatically. The only exception is objects that implement `Externalizable` or override `Serializable.writeObject/readObject` methods - such objects can be stored in the binary format and you have to have class definitions for them on the server side. More information on the binary format is provided [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller).

Finally I would recommend to take a look at [CacheQueryExample](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheQueryExample.java) that is delivered as a part of Ignite release. The object models used in this example are stored in the binary format.

Comment: Thank you! The approach with QueryEntity suits very well. Because we havn't class definition at all and building of binary object on runtime is the most suitable way for our application.